# Error 6412 - Cannot assign to read only property

Tags: angular, ngxs

I am trying to update the state model, but I am running into an issue (because I do not have enough experience with it yet).  Getting "core.mjs:6412 ERROR TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'decisionDate' of object '[object Object]'".

The issue is at the line I added "-->" to.  What have I done wrong/what am I missing?

```
@Action(ClerkAction.Review.UpdateSelectedDate)  
    onUpdateSelectedDate(ctx: StateContext<ClerkStateModel>, action: ClerkAction.Review.UpdateSelectedDate) {
        const DocumentList = ctx.getState().request.documents;
        const DocumentIndex = DocumentList.findIndex(item => item.guid === action.documentGuid);  
-->     DocumentList[DocumentIndex].decisionDate = action.newDate;  

        ctx.patchState({ 
            request: {
                ...ctx.getState().request,
                documents: DocumentList
            }        
        });
    
        ctx.dispatch(new NotificationAction.Loading(false));
    }
```

UPDATE and SOLUTION - 07-03-2023
So, I had to:

- I had to clone the original item (use the react ...)
- Then I had to replace the existing element of the collection, with the newly cloned element (along with its change).
- Then patchState

  ```
    const DocumentList = ctx.getState().request.documents;
    const DocumentIndex = DocumentList.findIndex(item => item.guid === action.documentGuid);
    var ItemToUpdate = {...DocumentList[DocumentIndex]};

    ItemToUpdate.decisionDate = action.newDate;

    const reconstruct = addOrReplace('guid', DocumentList, ItemToUpdate);
  ```

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option is to use [StateOperators](https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/operators)

In your case it should be something like:

> ```
> ctx.setState(
>   patch<ClerkStateModel>({
>     documents: updateItem(
>       item => item.guid === action.documentGuid,
>       patch({ decisionDate: action.newDate }
>     )
>   })
> );
> ```